# Determine the number of return values expected by Lua from inside a C extension function

Tags: c, lua

Every time a function in Lua is called, the number of return values is immediately known at the call site:

```
f() --0
local a, b = f() --2
local t = {f()} --LUA_MULTRET
local t = {f(), nil} --1
```

The same is true for the C API: both `lua_call` and `lua_pcall` are always provided with the expected number of return values (or `LUA_MULTRET`).

Thinking about performance, it might be advantageous for a Lua function to be able to determine the number of expected return values expressed by their callers, so as to avoid computing return values that the caller did not request (if the computation takes a long time):

```
int getstrings(lua_State *L)
{
    if(lua_numresults(L) > 0)
    {
        lua_pushstring(L, "a");
        if(lua_numresults(L) > 1)
        {
            lua_pushstring(L, "b");
            if(lua_numresults(L) > 2)
            {
                lua_pushstring(L, "c");
                return 3
            }
            return 2;
        }
        return 1
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming a hypothetical `lua_numresults` returns `size_t`, this function would produce only the that are really needed and will not take time to compute values that are guaranteed to be lost.

Another interesting example would be functions that return sequences:

```
int range(lua_State *L)
{
    size_t num = lua_numresults(L);
    for(size_t i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        lua_pushinteger(L, i);
    }
    return num;
}
```

The sequence is not "lazy" so something like `f(range())` cannot be done, but `local a, b, c = range()` returning 1, 2, 3 etc. might find its uses.

Is there anything like `lua_numresults` or a way to implement its functionality?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178545/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-illidans4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from Lua 5.3 sources, the expected number of results is located in the `CallInfo` structure. A new call info is created for every Lua call, and the most recent one is stored in `lua_State::ci` There doesn't appear to be any function that can return this value, but if one has access to the structure, it is fairly straightforward to get it:

```
#include "lua/lstate.h"

size_t lua_numresults(lua_State *L)
{
    return (size_t)L->ci->nresults;
}
```